# 1062 mysql ( sql alchemy) duplication error customisation

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-error-1064

IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry...)

This is the terminal error message that goes along with a 'lovely' white unhelpful '500 Internal Server Error' html page.

The application I am writing uses a flask template and mysql alchemy.

I would like to know, is there a way of customising this error?

I am aware that 400, 403,500 ect errors can be customised so my assumption is this follows a similar format.

I have also discovered the 'Ignore' mysql tag which turns the error into a warning and not an error, meaning you would not receive the html page however i have yet to discover how to implement this in a user helpful way.

Comment: Prolly you're facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039583/flask-custom-error-page-500-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately i might need to dive a little deep. You see Even though i have a personalised 500.html doc, If a duplication error does occur on my database i require a more indepth analysis of where the duplication occurs. So is there a way of isolating the 1062 error and redirecting it so that i might run my own code when it occurs?